# Android Selector Problem

Tags: android, listview, selector

i have a listview with a custom item_row.xml. I've defined a selector in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_bg" >
</item>
<item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/header_bg" >
</item>
<item
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_bg" >
</item>
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/header_bg">
</item>
```

and then put into item_row.xml in this way:

```
    <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="70dip"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@drawable/list_selector">
```

I want 2 things:

- When i move with arrow keys, the item selected changed its background. It's works fine with the actual implementation of selector.
- When i press a item, the item changed its background too, but it doesn't work with the actual selector.

Any idea? I try to set also into the ListView android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
but it doesn't work neither.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should model your `StateListDrawable` after the one used by Android itself for `ListView` selectors. You can find this in `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/$VERSION/data/res/drawable/list_selector_background.xml`, where `$ANDROID_HOME` is where your Android SDK is installed and `$VERSION` is some Android version (e.g., `android-2.1`). Then, apply the list selector via `android:listSelector` in the `ListView` in your layout XML.

Comment: Now i have the selector working fine, but the problem is.. if i have a background for the item_row_list, the selector doesn't appear. and i can't put on top because it covers the information of the row..

thanks!

Comment: Make the selector transparent or translucent, and put it on top.

Comment: it still doesn't work. If i use  
   
<item 
  android:state_pressed="true"
  android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" >
</item>


i can't see the selector and it covers the text too.

What i want is: 

- See a selector traslucent which appears when i move along the list with arrow keys and when i press one item.

If you could help me i would be very grateful